# Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I'm struggling to solve the following issue:

**Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService**

Here is my Log:

[image]

Im using Xamarin Forms 3.1.0.583944 with Microsoft.AppCenter.Push 1.8.0, Android API 27

I have researched and applied possible solutions (double/triple checked):

- Deleted Bin/Obj folders
- Enabled Multi-Dex
- Updated Google Play Services

**NOTHING WORKED**

**Update:**
Issue comes when I try to configure the AppCenter Push:

```
AppCenter.Start(AppConfig.AppCenterAndroidKey, typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Push));

Push.SetEnabledAsync(AppConfig.EnablePush);
```

**Update 1 : Downgraded the Microsoft AppCenter and Push to 1.7 and it is working for me.**

Comment: What are the Mono linker and Proguard settings for this build configuration?

Comment: @SushiHangover I have not enabled Pro-Guard and Linking SDK assemblies only.